# Passing Null value parameter to dynamic SQL query. How can this be successfully executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a dynamic SQL query. where parameters are passed dynamically. I first wrote similar to following code.

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @Id ='RMH_108'
SET @query ='Select * 
             FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId =' + @Id
PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

> [image: Error]

Then I wrote this.

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @Id ='RMH_108'
SET @query ='Select * 
             FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId = '''+@Id+''''
PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

> [image: ERROR]

This time code successfully executed. Since parameter can be empty I need to convert that to null. I modified the code and wrote this

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @Id = ''
SET @Id = NULLIF(@Id,'')
-- COMMENTED SET @Id ='RMH_108'

SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId = '''+@Id+''''
PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

> [image: Error]

No errors. Query crashed.
Does anybody come up with this sort of problem ?

Comment: [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog would be a good read for you, I think.

Comment: try this SET @query = 'Select * 
             FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId=''' + isnull(Convert(VARCHAR, @id), '') + '''   '

EXEC (@query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert it to NULL just check with your value

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
 SET @Id = ''


                            -- COMMENTED SET @Id ='RMH_108'
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId = '''+@Id+''''
PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `sp_executeSQL` and remove string concatenation like this. I am assuming that if `NULL` is passed you want all the rows to be returned.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @Id ='RMH_108'SET @query ='Select * 
                               FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
                               WHERE RMHierarchyId = @Id OR @ID IS NULL'
PRINT @query
EXEC sp_executeSQL @query,N'@Id NVARCHAR(MAX)',@Id
```

Comment: Thanks . this also gave the result.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]'
IF @Id IS NOT NULL
   SET @query = @query + ' WHERE RMHierarchyId = '''+@Id+''''
```

If the parameter comes from client you better do with parametrized query(see @ughai's answer) in order to exclude `sql injection` possibility...

Comment: @Giogi Nakeuri . Thanks. That gave the result.But i have a question. what happens if we have multiple parameter like this. do i need to check each parameter to null value ?

Comment: You should recommend the use of `sp_executesql` with parameters instead of string concatenation

Answer (score 3):

Anything with the arithmetic of NULL will yield NULL.

I'd do this way if NULL is meant for returning all rows:

```
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]' +
            case when @Id is not null then 
            ' WHERE RMHierarchyId = ''' + @Id + '''' else '' end
```

And this way if to really want to have rows with NULL condition:

```
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId ' + case when @Id is null 
             then 'is NULL' else '= ''' + @Id +'''' end
```

But then again, it would always be better to avoid dynamic query at all cost. Consider:

```
Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand] WHERE  
             (RMHierarchyId = @Id or nullif(@Id, '') is null)
```

And:

```
Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand] WHERE (RMHierarchyId = @Id or
             (RMHierarchyId is null and @Id is null))
```

Comment: "_Anything with the arithmetic of NULL will yield NULL._": one would think that, but I just found a case where that isn't true: [EXECUTE T-SQL string concatenates NULL variable as an empty string instead of making concatenated string NULL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35660251-execute-t-sql-string-concatenates-null-variable-as).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE RMHierarchyId = ' + ISNULL( @Id , '')
```

Comment: Same result. No output.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV It doesn't work. What is this syntax '(at)query' ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SET @query = 'Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand] WHERE RMHierarchyId=''' + isnull(Convert(VARCHAR, @id), '') + ''' '

    EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Id nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);

SET @query  = N'SELECT * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand] ' + CHAR(10)

IF @Id IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + N'WHERE RMHierarchyId = @param_id'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + N'WHERE RMHierarchyId IS NULL'
END

PRINT @query

EXEC sp_executesql
        @statement = @query,
        @params = N'@param_id VARCHAR(MAX)',
        @param_id = @Id
```

You should used parameterized query when using dynamic sql to avoid SQL Injection. Read [**this**](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) for more information.

If you want to return all rows if the `@Id` passed is `NULL`, just remove the `ELSE` part.

Comment: one of the valid value is `'RMH_108'`. `@Param` should be `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` instead of `@param_id integer`

Answer (score 0):

You can also write as:

```
SET @query ='Select * FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
             WHERE 1 = case when '''+@Id+''' = '''' then 1 when  RMHierarchyId =      
             '''+@Id+''' then 1 else 0 end '
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why no one suggesting there is no need to use dynamic SQL here

```
Select * 
FROM [A06].[Syn_RMDemand]
WHERE NULLIF(@Id, '') IS NULL OR RMHierarchyId = @Id
```